# Under what conditions the operator $-\sum \partial_{x_i} a_{ij} \partial_{x_j}$ is self-adjoint?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, laplacian, self-adjoint-operators

Define:
$$
\mathcal{L} = -\sum_{i,j} a_{ij} \partial_{x_i}  \partial_{x_j},
$$
where $a_{i,j}=a_{j,i}$. If $a_{i,j}=\delta_{i,j}$ the operator is the Laplacian which is known to be self-adjoint in the $L^2$ norm. 
For other choices of coefficients $a_{i,j}$ - is the operator $\mathcal{L}$ self adjoint in the $L^2 $ norm?

If we restrict our attention to the $\mathbb{R}^3 $ case, we have that
$$
\int_\Omega v \mathcal{L}u \, d \vec{x} = \int_{\partial \Omega} v(A\nabla u) \cdot \hat{n} dS - \int_\Omega (A\nabla u)\cdot \nabla v d \vec{x},
$$
$$
\int_\Omega u \mathcal{L}v \, d \vec{x} = \int_{\partial \Omega} u(A\nabla v) \cdot \hat{n} dS - \int_\Omega (A\nabla v)\cdot \nabla u d \vec{x},
$$
where $v \in C_c^{\infty} (\Omega)$, $A = (a_{i,j})$. From the symmetricity of $A$, the second term in both equalities is the same, but is there any reason for the first term to also be equal in the two equalities?

Comment: If $v \in C^\infty_c(\Omega)$ then, in particular, $v_{|\partial \Omega}=0$ and $ \nabla v_{|\partial \Omega}=0$ so both first terms are $0$.

Comment: Can you please add some details about why $v_{|\partial \Omega}=0$ and  $ \nabla v_{|\partial \Omega}=0$? I understand that $v \in C^\infty_c(\Omega)$ means that the support of $v$ contains $\Omega$, but can't $\Omega$ be closed? (checking an operator is self adjoint requires checking only on open sets?). Thanks!

Comment: In fact when describing an operator also need to precise the set $\Omega$ and the the boundary condition. For example this is why we sometimes talk about the "DIrichlet Laplacian" and the "Neumann Laplacian". When there is no precision it is often about open set with DIrichlet boundary conditions.

Comment: Thanks @Delta-u - so $v_{|\partial \Omega}=0$ because of Dirichlet boundary conditions? or because $v \in C^\infty_c(\Omega)$ ?

Comment: Both justification are correct. In fact the Dirichlet boundary conditions and $v \in C^\infty_c(\Omega)$ are the same. Indeed a definition of the $H^1_0(\Omega)$, the space in which the Dirichlet cboundary conditions are prescribed, is to be the closure of $C^\infty_c(\Omega)$ under the $H^1$ norm. So if you choose your dense subset to be $C^\infty_c$ you recover automatically Dirichlet BC and in order to solve with Dirichlet boundary conditions the usual choice is to take $C^\infty_c$ as the dense subset.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot!